# Core Graphics clipping not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have this code to color an area between an inside and outside boundary.

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);
CGContextAddPath(context, inlinePath);
CGContextEOClip(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, outlinePath);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _myColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This is part of a local routine `drawChartInContext:`.
It works great when I generate an image like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 2.0);
[self drawChartInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But when I call it from `drawRect` I just get the whole `outlinePath` area filled with `_myColor`.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawChartInContext:context];
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It was a combination of two oversights:

1. `inlinePath` had zero area (a special case that is valid)
2. `myColor` had 1.0 alpha (a configuration mistake).